# Extension to turn off certain page element?

Tags: google-chrome-extensions, firefox-extensions, safari-extensions

Does anyone know of a browser extension that allows you to disable an HTML element by id or class on a given web page?

I prefer to use Chrome, but a Safari or Firefox solution would be great too.

Example of a use for it:

Suppose I want to check my Facebook (for notifications or messages) but I don't want to see the newsfeed.

Comment: I would suggest looking into [Userscripts](http://userscripts.org/), for Firefox you'd need the Greasemonkey Add-on, but chrome supports many by default (that is really dependent on how the userscript was written, however).  Otherwise, you can create your own userscript that accomplishes your task.  Follow the examples on the link, it's pretty easy.  If you know the id of the element, it's basically `$('#iDIWantToHide').remove();`

Comment: For Chrome you can use TamperMonkey which is similar to Greasemonkey for Firefox. Check out the ID Hider userscript. However, the answer provided by @m4573r offers a far more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On firefox, I personally use [AdBlock Plus Element Hiding Helper](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/elemhidehelper/), coupled with [Adblock Plus](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/adblock-plus/). With a simple shortcut, it allows to visually select the element you want to hide, and adjusting the tag to your liking is extremely easy. I use this on every single news site I visit, to remove useless headers/footers/banners/social bars that clutter them. I never used it on facebook though, so I can't guarantee the result.

It seems that the extension also exist for chrome ([here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adblock%20-element-hiding-h/chmimgmjdabgiilljdjfbonifbhiglao?hl=en)), although I never tested it.

Answer (score 0):

Check out "Click to Remove Element" (CTRE):

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/click-to-remove-element-ff/